# Stop statically served React app from calling server path

Tags: node.js, reactjs, express, react-router

My app has the default homepage at "/", and a contact page at "/contact". When I ran the react server(localhost:3000) and express server(localhost:8000) separately, the navigation between these pages works fine as handled by "react-router-dom" below.

Frontend React, Routing.tsx:

```
import React from "react";
import { BrowserRouter, Route, Switch } from "react-router-dom";
import Contact from "../pages/Contact/Contact";
import Main from "../pages/Main/Main";
import Error from "../pages/Error/Error";

function Routing() {
  return (
    <BrowserRouter>
      <Switch>
        <Route path="/error" component={Error} />
        <Route path="/contact" component={Contact} />
        <Route path="/" component={Main} />
      </Switch>
    </BrowserRouter>
  );
}

export default Routing;
```

Now I built the react app using `npm run build`, and placed the "build" folder inside my backend express server to be served, as per deployment doc [here](https://create-react-app.dev/docs/deployment#other-solutions). Then I ran "npm run dev" to start the server.

However, whenever I try to navigate to the /contact page, **it issues a server call to "localhost:8000/contact" instead of being handled by the frontend routing.** Of course the server doesn't have that route, and all my server routes are prefaced with "/api/" anyway.

[image]

How can we prevent frontend navigation from calling the server routes?

More code below, thanks.

Backend Express, App.ts:

```
import express from "express";
import path from "path";

class App {
  private _app: express.Application;
  private readonly _port: number | string = process.env.PORT || 8000;

  constructor(controllers: any[]) {
    this._app = express();
    this.initializeControllers(controllers);
    this.initializeMiddleWares();
    this.initHostingReactUI();
  }

  public start() {
    this._app.listen(this._port, () => {
      console.log(`App listening on the port ${this._port}`);
    });
  }

  private initializeControllers(controllers: any[]) {
    controllers.forEach((controller) => {
      this._app.use("/api", controller.router);
    });
  }

  public initializeMiddleWares() {
    require("./src/middleware/express.middleware")(this._app);
  }

  public initHostingReactUI() {
    // I am aware that you can do "/*" below to catch all routes, but that doesn't solve my issue as it still calls the backend for every non-api routes that should be handled by frontend routing.
    this._app.get("/", (req, res) => {
      res.sendFile(path.join(__dirname, "build", "index.html"));
    });
  }
}

export default App;
```

Backend Folder structure with Build folder:

[image]

If needed:

[Backend github source.](https://github.com/SeanLuo-FSWD/RTBE.git)

[Frontend github source](https://github.com/SeanLuo-FSWD/pm_fe.git)

Comment: Use a server like nginx to serve frontend files and write a proxy pass directive for all calls to `/api/` location which you should recirect to express. Also, in your frontend it should not use a port as such in code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are two ways to combine the routes between the frontend and backend:

**If access from `http://localhost:3000`**

You need to boot both frontend and backend.

In this case, all your backend request urls will start with `http://localhost:3000` (if you didn't specify a base url). To solve this issue, add a line in the root of your client-side package.json file:

```json
{
    "proxy": "http://localhost:8000"
}
```

After that, frontend will redirect all the unknown routes to backend.

**If access from `http://localhost:8000`**

You only need to boot the backend.

Since React application is one-page application, which means there is only one html entry (index.html). Now we need a route to serve the frontend routes in the backend:

```js
// place this in the end after the other routes
app.get('*', (req, res) => 
    res.sendFile(path.join(__dirname, "build", "index.html"));
})
```

The routing system will check if the route exists among the backend routes. If not, then serve index.html and check if the route exists among the frontend routes. Therefore, in the frontend you should guard the urls by returning a 404 page when not found.

Answer (score 1):

Do you mean navigate through the app? if not, navigating to the page by the URL or refreshing the page always will send a request to the server, which should return the app index.js.

All you need to do is to place the last route which is serving react (You can use `app.get('*', .....)` or placing`app.use((req, res) => {...})` without route).

In this case, when the request came to the server, the server will search for the route top-to-bottom, if the requested route is not api then it's will serve the client-side app.